Cloudinary Plugin Error in Sanity Studio: "cloudinary.asset resolve this issue"
Question:
I'm encountering difficulties while trying to smoothly integrate the Cloudinary plugin into my Sanity Studio project. Despite thorough consultation of official documentation and tutorial resources, the plugin doesn't seem to be functioning correctly.
Error Message:
post:document→fields→[1]:cloudinary.asset resolve this issue
See the error Screenshot
Environment:
Operating System: Debian 64 bit
Sanity Version: ^3.36.4
Code Snippets:
Here's how I've configured the Cloudinary plugin in my Sanity Studio:
import { defineConfig } from "sanity";
import { visionTool } from "@sanity/vision";
import { structureTool } from "sanity/structure";
import { cloudinaryAssetSourcePlugin } from "sanity-plugin-cloudinary";
import { schemaTypes } from "./schemaTypes";


export default defineConfig({
    // SANITY META CONFIGURATIONS
    name: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_NAME,
    title: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_TITLE,

    // SANITY API CONFIGURATIONS
    projectId: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_PROJECT_ID as string,
    dataset: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_DATASET || "production",

    // SCHEMA & Plugins
    schema: {
        types: schemaTypes,
    },
    plugins: [
        structureTool(),
        visionTool(),
        cloudinaryAssetSourcePlugin()
    ],
});

And here's how I've defined the Cloudinary asset field in my document schema:
import { defineField, defineType } from "sanity";


export default defineType({
    name: "post",
    title: "Post",
    type: "document",
    fields: [
        defineField({
            type: "cloudinary.asset",
            name: "image",
            description: "This asset is served from Cloudinary",
        }),
        // ... Other Field
    ],
});

Expected Output:
I expect to resolve the error related to the Cloudinary plugin in my Sanity Studio project. Upon resolution, I anticipate successfully integrating the Cloudinary plugin with my document schema without encountering any further issues.
Additional Information:

Referred to official documentation for Cloudinary plugin: Sanity Plugin Cloudinary.
Additionally, I have watched a tutorial video on Cloudinary's official YouTube channel titled "Integrating Cloudinary with Sanity Studio", available here.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!
